# How to determine the eigenvalues and eigenvector of the Householder matrix

Tags: solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Here is the specification again:

Let $ w \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and $||w||=1$. The $n \times n$- matrix.

$$ P:=I-2ww^t $$

is called the Householder transform and $w$ is called the Householder vector.

Determine the eigenvalues of P and its eigenvectors.

Here is my way of determining the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Does this make any sense or is there something missing?

A Householder transform is orthogonal ($P^{-1}=P^t$) and symmetric ($P^t=P$).

I.e. it holds:

$$ (I - 2ww^t)^t = I - 2ww^t $$

$$ (I - 2ww^T)^2 = I - 4ww^T + 4w(w^Tw)w^T = I $$

Here $w^t w = 1$, since according to the above $w$ is a unit vector.

Eigenvalues of orthogonal matrices have the absolute value $1$, since multiplication by an orthogonal matrix is isometry (length-preserving).

Show here in a short proof that holds:
Let A be an orthogonal matrix and $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an eigenvector of A to eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\lambda \in \{ \pm 1\}$ holds.

Proof. Let A be an orthogonal matrix and $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an eigenvector of A at eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. As an orthogonal matrix, A is length-faithful:

$$ ||v||=||Av||=||\lambda v||=| \lambda | ||v||$$.
The last equality follows from the bilinearity of the scalar product.

As an eigenvector $v \ne 0$ and thus $| \lambda |=1$.

By assumption, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, so $ \lambda \in \{ \pm 1 \} $. $\square $\\

Since the Householder matrix $P = I - 2ww^T$ is real and symmetric, its eigenvalues are real.  The only real numbers with absolute value $1$ are then $\pm 1$.\\

Since $Pw = w - 2w(w^t w) = -w$, $-1$ is eigenvalue of $P$ and $vw$ for any $v \in \mathbb{R}, v \ne 0$, is an associated eigenvector.

For $x \in w^t$, i.e. $x^tw = 0$, holds:
$$Px = x-2ww^tx=x$$,
i.e. 1 is eigenvalue of P and every $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n},x \ne 0$ with $x^tw=0$ is eigenvector.

By decomposing
\begin{equation}
y = \langle y, w \rangle w + (\ y - \langle y, w \rangle w )\
\end{equation}

into its projection on span$ \{ w \} $ and a perpendicular part, one sees that there are no other eigenvectors of P.

P therefore has the eigenvalues
$ \lambda_1 = 1 (\ (\ n-1 )\ -fold )\ $ with eigenspace $E_{\lambda_1} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} : x^tw = 0 \}$ and $\lambda_2 = -1 $ (single) with eigenspace $E_{\lambda_2} = \{ vw : v \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

The eigenspace at eigenvalue 1 is the mirror plane, i.e. the orthogonal complement of the $v$ generated one-dimensional subspace.

Comment: $P^2=I$ so you immediately have that all eigenvalues are $\pm1$.

Comment: $x \in \omega^t$ should be $x \in \omega^\perp$ `x \in \omega^\perp` $\omega^t$ is just a row vector, not a set of vectors.